# Is their a way to remove this attribute error? or does it include an import

Tags: lambda, token, spacy, attributeerror, named-entity-recognition

I am struggling on how to fix this error, I want all found NER tags (even if two or three found per tweet) to appear in a new column showing the NER found.

```
import math
NDF = nlp(open('tweet_data_clean (3).csv', encoding="utf8").read())
nlp =spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
loc_labels = ['GPE', 'LOC']
ner_locations = []

#functin
def get_NER_locations(row):
  tweet_id = row['id']
  tweet = row['tweet']
  doc = nlp(tweet)
  for ent in doc.ents:
    if ent.label_ in loc_labels:
      ner_locations.append([tweet_id, ent.text, ent.label_, spacy.explain(ent.label_)])
NDF.apply(lambda row : get_NER_location (row))
ner_NDF = pd.DataFrame(ner_locations, columns=['id', 'ent', 'label', 'label_desc'])
merged_NDF = pd.merge(NDF, ner_NDF, on='id', how='outer')
```

The error which appears is :
AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' object has no attribute 'apply'.

It is not happy with the third line from the bottom. I have added it below for clarity purposes. My experience with Lambda is not much and would appreciate if anyone can explain why the error is occurring as from research its to do with the use of Apply and Lambda together.

NDF.apply(lambda row : get_NER_location (row))